# What options need to be set for Simplify to perform a certain manipulations similar to FullSimplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

`Simplify` performs algebraic transformations and is fast, while `FullSimplify` tries a wide range of transformations involving elementary/special functions but is slow.

I would like to endow `Simplify` with the following ability of `FullSimplify` without compromising speed:

```
expr=(4 a^2)/(a^2 - b^2)^2 - (3 b^2)/(a^2 - b^2)^2 - 8/(b^2 - c^2)^2;

Simplify[expr]
```

> (4 a^2)/(a^2 - b^2)^2 - (3 b^2)/(a^2 - b^2)^2 - 8/(b^2 - c^2)^2

```
FullSimplify[expr]
```

> (4 a^2 - 3 b^2)/(a^2 - b^2)^2 - 8/(b^2 - c^2)^2

For my purposes, `expr` is only a sum of rational expressions involving atomic symbols.  What `TransformationFunctions` (or other options) do I need to give to `Simplify` so that it can combine certain terms, like `FullSimplify`.

I tried `Simplify[expr, TransformationFunctions->Together]`, but it doesn't work.

Alternatively, can I give `FullSimplify` options to make it go faster?

Comment: you might want to check out the option `TimeConstraint`.  For example `FullSimplify[expr, TimeConstraint -> 1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often, it is desirable to apply `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` to parts of an expression and then recombine the parts.  A particularly effective function for this purpose is `Collect`.  For instance,

```
Collect[expr, a^2 - b^2, Simplify]
(* (4 a^2 - 3 b^2)/(a^2 - b^2)^2 - 8/(b^2 - c^2)^2 *)
```

Although there is no need to use `FullSimplify`in this case, it runs faster here when used with `Collect`.

Although not well described in the documentation, `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` can be used with options in `Collect`:

```
Collect[expr, a^2 - b^2, Simplify[#, options]&]
```